# Catch SomeException with ExceptT

Tags: haskell, exception, monad-transformers

I'm trying to use the `ExceptT` monad transformer to catch any exception thrown by a function, like so:

```
import Control.Exception
import Control.Monad.Trans.Except

badFunction :: ExceptT SomeException IO ()
badFunction = throw DivideByZero

main :: IO ()
main = do
    r <- runExceptT badFunction
    case r of Left _ -> putStrLn "caught error"
              Right _ -> putStrLn "nope, didn't catch no error"
```

... but the exception happily flies by.  What am I doing wrong?

**Edit**: to clarify, the aim is to catch *any* exception thrown by a function, regardless of how the exception was thrown.  If it makes any difference, the real function call is at the bottom of a fairly deep monad transformer stack. I don't mind missing things like thrown strings (bad programmer!).

Answer (score 6):

First, you catch your runtime exception. It can be done by using either `monad-control` (and `lifted-base`) or `exceptions`. Michael Snoyman has a nice article comparing the two: [Exceptions and monad transformers](http://www.yesodweb.com/blog/2014/06/exceptions-transformers)

Second, you embed the caught exception in `ExceptT`.

Here's the complete working code:

```
import Control.Exception.Lifted
import Control.Monad.Trans.Except

badFunction :: ExceptT SomeException IO ()
badFunction = throw DivideByZero

intercept
  :: ExceptT SomeException IO a
  -> ExceptT SomeException IO a
intercept a = do
  r <- try a
  case r of
    Right x -> return x
    Left e -> throwE e

main :: IO ()
main = do
    r <- runExceptT $ intercept badFunction
    case r of Left _ -> putStrLn "caught error"
              Right _ -> putStrLn "nope, didn't catch no error"
```

A more compact (but perhaps somewhat less obvious) definition of `intercept` is

```
intercept
  :: ExceptT SomeException IO a
  -> ExceptT SomeException IO a
intercept = handle throwE
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you want `throwE`, not `throw`.

Also, it'll be an `ArithException`, not a `SomeException`.