# Handling exceptions (ExceptT) in chain of actions

Tags: haskell, exception

I am trying to use an exception to skip parts of the code here. Instead of getting caught by `catcheE` and resuming normal behavior all following actions in the `mapM_` chain get skipped.

I looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26385809/catch-someexception-with-exceptt) and it appears that `catchE` ~ `main` and `checkMaybe` ~ `intercept`.
I also checked the implementation of `mapM_`to be sure it does what i want it to, but i don't understand how the Left value can escape `dlAsset` to affect the behavior of `mapM_`.

I refactored this from a version where i simply used an empty string as an exception marker for the failed lookup. In that version `checkMaybe` just returned a `Right` value immediately and it worked (matching on `""` to 'catch')

```hs
import Data.HashMap.Strict as HM hiding (map) 
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as BS
import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as BSC8
import qualified JSONParser as P -- my module

retrieveAssets :: (Text -> Text) -> ExceptT Text IO ()
retrieveAssets withName = withManager $ (lift ((HM.keys . P.assets)
  <$> P.raw) ) >>= mapM_ f
  where
  f = \x -> dlAsset x "0.1246" (withName x)

dlAsset :: Text -> Text -> Text -> ReaderT Manager (ExceptT Text IO) ()
dlAsset name size dest = do
  req <- lift $ (P.assetLookup name size <$> P.raw) >>= checkMaybe
    name >>= parseUrl . unpack -- lookup of a url
  res <- httpLbs req 
  lift $ (liftIO $ BS.writeFile (unpack dest) $ responseBody res)
    `catchE` (\_ -> return ()) -- always a Right value?
    where 
      checkMaybe name a = case a of
        Nothing -> ExceptT $ fmap Left $ do
          BSC8.appendFile "./resources/images/missingFiles.txt" $ 
            BSC8.pack $ (unpack name) ++ "\n"
          putStrLn $ "lookup of " ++ (unpack name) ++ " failed"
          return name
        Just x  -> lift $ pure x
```

(had to reformat to become somewhat readable here)

edit: i'd like to understand what actually happens here, that would probably help me more than knowing which part of the code is wrong.

Comment: What are these `main` and `intercept` you speak of? What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: main and intercept are what the linked answer uses in its example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your call to `catchE` only covered the very last line of `dlAsset`. It needs to be moved to the left of the do-notation indentation level to cover all of the do notation.